# check expire date of auth token saved to redux before every fetch() in react-native

Tags: react-native, jwt, fetch-api

In my react-native app, I have a `jwt`saved to `localStorage` by `redux-persist`. I need to check the expire date of token before every fetch request to API. But I don't want to implement this process of date comparing within every page, because there are dozens of pages where I make a request to API.  Maybe I can write custom method that wrappes `fetch` and check the expire date inside or before every fetch to dispatch action that check whether token expired? I'm stuck here. Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hey, to confirm, what would you like to happen when the jwt token is expired? Log the user out?

Answer (score 0):

This is an overview of how you can solve your problem.

Step by Step

1. /login
2. Successful login
3. Server returns { token, refreshToken }

Now for making any request ( protected i.e only logged in user needs to be shown or access a particular resource on server)

1. send token with each protected request in Authorization header
2. server validates the token
3. in case of expired token server returns expired token error
4. now client receives the expired token error
5. next client dispatches an action to get new token
6. new action should send an api call to server to get new token passing refreshToken
7. after validation of refreshToken server returns new accessToken and refreshToken, in case passed refreshToken was invalid return an error and client should logOut the user
8. If new accessToken is received update the app state with new accessToken and refreshToken

This is just an overview but you can add more security measures to it such as only few times token can be requested via refreshToken and after that user must login again.